# Django's cache framework - auto deletion?

Tags: django, caching

I have encountered the following problem and I have no clue why.

I use Django's cache framework to cache part of my site.

I have set the expires time as 15mins.

Sometimes when I am checking with the database, there is no record in the cache table. At first, I suspect Django will remove the expired cache in the database.

But later, I can find some expired caches still exist in the table.

I want to ask how Django handles the cache in the database?

Does Django auto-remove all the expired cache in the table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How and when the cache is purged depends on which cache backend you are using. Generally the cache will only be purged periodically, when the number of items in it exceeds a specified limit (**as opposed to when they have expired** - Django does not check this until and unless you try to fetch an item from the cache).

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#cache-arguments) on the cache configuration:

> Cache backends that implement their own culling strategy (i.e., the `locmem`, `filesystem` and `database` backends) will honor the following options:
>
> `MAX_ENTRIES`: The maximum number of entries allowed in the cache before old values are deleted. This argument defaults to 300.
>
> `CULL_FREQUENCY`: The fraction of entries that are culled when `MAX_ENTRIES` is reached. The actual ratio is `1 / CULL_FREQUENCY`, so set `CULL_FREQUENCY` to 2 to cull half the entries when `MAX_ENTRIES` is reached. This argument should be an integer and defaults to 3.

So when and how your cache is cleared depends on these parameters. By default the entire cache is not cleared - only a fraction of entries are removed.